# creating a CustomView

Tags: android, custom-controls

I am trying to implement [this game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puli_Joodam), and I am confused about how to start.

Should I use ImageButtons and implement this game, or should Icreate some custom view?

I am not asking you the code, but what custom view I should create. Basically, I need a plan as to how to implement this game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like line drawing.
So extend View, implement onDraw method, and there draw lines to Canvas.
If there're other parts to draw, you may possibly use Bitmap to draw these onto the Canvas.